# php array with implode function

Tags: php, arrays, implode

I am getting array like this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Earl E
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => Juan Morefore DeRhode
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 36
        [name] => Mack Truck
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 37
        [name] => Phil Addio
    )
```

My Loop looks like this:

```
$name_arr_val = array();
for($i=0; $i<count($name); $i++){
    $name_arr_val[] = str_replace(',', '', $name[$i]['name']);
}
echo $name_list = '"' . implode('", "', $name_arr_val) . '"';
```

How to genrate out like bellow:

```
['1', 'Earl E'],
['2', 'Juan Morefore DeRhode'],
['36', 'Mack Truck'],
['37', 'Phil Addio']
```

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: do you need just an output or a new array with exact indices?

Comment: If you're generating JSON, take a look at `json_encode`.  All you have to do is create an array in the right format (which involves simply turning `array('id' => $id, 'name' => $name)` into `array($id, $name)`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
$output = array();

foreach ( $array as $item ) {
    $id = $item['id'];
    $name = $item['name'];

    // single quotes
    $output[] = "['$id', '$name']";        
    // double quotes
    $output[] = '["' . $id . '", "' . $name . '"]';  
}

echo implode( ",\n", $output );
```

But maybe what you are looking for is a JSON?

```
echo json_encode( $array );
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   $print="";
   foreach($arrayname as $arr){
     $print.='['.$arr['id'].','.' '.$arr['name'].']'.'<br>'
    }echo $print;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps,

```
$result = '';
foreach($main_array as $k=>$val)
{
   if($result!='')
      $result .= ',';

   $result .= "['".$val['id']."', '".$val['name']."']";
}

echo ($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

can you please used this :

```
$output = array();
foreach ( $array as $item ) { 
    $output[] = "['".$item['id']."', '".$item['name']."']";        
}
echo implode( ",\n", $output );
```